# Как переделать sql запрос в php переменные?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$cid = (int)$this->customer->getId();
                $pid = (int)$product_query->row['product_id'];
                $customer_new = $this->db->query("
                   SELECT tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id AS prod_id, sum(tb01.quantity) AS sum_quantity
                   FROM oc_order_product AS tb01
                   LEFT JOIN oc_order AS tb02 ON tb01.order_id = tb02.order_id 
                   LEFT JOIN oc_customer AS tb03 ON tb02.customer_id = tb03.customer_id
                   WHERE tb03.customer_id = '{$cid}'
                   GROUP BY tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id
                ");
                $ssd = array(
                    'prod_id' => $customer_new->row['prod_id'], 
                    'sum_quantity' => $customer_new->row['sum_quantity'], 


                );

print_r($ssd);
```

Почему то только один product_id выбирает

```
Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 )
```

Comment: ошибку к вопросу то добавьте

Comment: error 500 не говорит ни о чём. Читайте php-логи на сервере

Comment: phpmyadmin или что-либо подобное для sql запросов используете?

Comment: Да все set портит я не знаю как без php ошибок "" проставить еще переменная sql @customer

Comment: @Bistore.bi-group 1. `"AAA \"$BBB\" CCC"`, 2. `'AAA "'.$BBB.'" CCC'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без `set`

```
$customer_new = $this->db->query("
   SELECT tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id, sum(tb01.quantity) AS sum_quantity
   FROM oc_order_product AS tb01
   LEFT JOIN oc_order AS tb02 ON tb01.order_id = tb02.order_id 
   LEFT JOIN oc_customer AS tb03 ON tb02.customer_id = tb03.customer_id
   WHERE tb03.customer_id = '{$cid}'
   GROUP BY tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id
");
```

UPD:
Если я правильно понял документацию, то должно быть так

```
$cid = (int)$this->customer->getId();
$pid = (int)$product_query->row['product_id'];
$customer_new = $this->db->query("
  SELECT tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id AS prod_id, sum(tb01.quantity) AS sum_quantity
  FROM oc_order_product AS tb01
  LEFT JOIN oc_order AS tb02 ON tb01.order_id = tb02.order_id 
  LEFT JOIN oc_customer AS tb03 ON tb02.customer_id = tb03.customer_id
  WHERE tb03.customer_id = '{$cid}'
  GROUP BY tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id
");

$rows = $customer_new->rows;
$ssd = array();
foreach($rows as $index => $row){
  $ssd[] = array(
    'prod_id' => $row['prod_id'], 
    'sum_quantity' => $row['sum_quantity']
  );
}

print_r($ssd);
```

Comment: Можете посмотреть еще плз сейчас результат и вопрос еще 1

Comment: а сколько у него продуктов у данного пользователя?

Comment: попробуйте убрать группировку

Comment: А мне нужно quantity получать( это количество товаров общее с каждого продукт айди и после уже минусовать это количество общее)

Comment: Простите, но я Вас не понимаю)

Comment: GROUP BY tb03.customer_id, tb01.product_id 
Мне нужно что бы покупки по product_id сумировались   
но в массиве выходило Array ( [prod_id] => 40 [sum_quantity] => 10 ) Array ( [prod_id] => 45 [sum_quantity] => 5 ) Array ( [prod_id] => 41 [sum_quantity] => 1 ) каждый товар по айди отдельно но группировка по сумме

Comment: обновил ответ. Проверяйте